# How application state is maintained in backbone.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

How can we maintain application state in Backbone.js as we have Sessions and Application variables in asp.net. Please guide I am stuck here. I know we have StateManager there in backbone.js but I don't think it has this functionality. Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please refer this tutorials...

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/11/backbonejs-router-tutorial.html

Comment: As I am newbie to Backbone. If I understand your answer routers can be used for this purpose for maintaining application state ?